# Pointer assignment to dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Basically all I am trying to do is assign something (a Polynomial) to a dynamic array at a given index, overwriting whatever is there.  For simplicity I just made subtract() return a pointer to the first element in the polynomialArray.  So, this code should copy the contents of the first element and replace another element (I know that a deep copy is necessary, and that is implemented in subtract).  I have been spoiled by java (and you kind folks)...

When I go to print it at the index at which it is copied to, there is nothing there.
Usually something like `Poly1 = 2x^3 + 4x` would print, but instead it just prints `Poly1 =`.

Compiles fine and runs, but does not do what I need it to. EDIT: Runs fine if there wasn't anything at that index.  If there is something at the index, seg fault.

```
//Portion of main from another file
  Polynomial* subtracted = subtract(op1_index, op2_index);
  insert(subtracted, diff_index);
  printPolynomial(diff_index);

//Methods in question (utils file)
  void insert(Polynomial* element, int index) {
    if(index > num_polynomial) {
      polynomialArray = (Polynomial*)realloc(polynomialArray, (index + 1) * sizeof(Polynomial));
    }
    free(polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm);
    polynomialArray[index] = *element;  // Problem here?
  }

  Polynomial* subtract(int op1_index, int op2_index) {
    return &polynomialArray[0];
  }

//Typedefs accessible in main and utils file 
  typedef struct term { 
    int exponent; 
    int coefficient; 
  } Term;  

  typedef struct polynomial { 
    Term *polynomialTerm; 
  } Polynomial; 



//variables accessible in utils file
      static Polynomial *polynomialArray;
      int num_polynomial; // counter to keep track of the number of polynomials
```

Comment: You can stop adding the `programming-languages` tag to your questions. It's not necessary.

Comment: can you show your print function?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here `free(polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm);` if index > num_polynomial, then the value here `polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm` is garbage. you don't need to free it. instead you should write it something like that:

```
void insert(Polynomial* element, int index) {
    if(index >= num_polynomial) {                     /*  probably should be >= depends on your implementation   */
      polynomialArray = (Polynomial*)realloc(polynomialArray, (index + 1) * sizeof(Polynomial));
    }
    else
    {
        free(polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm);
    }
    polynomialArray[index] = *element; 
  }
```

also, this is a bit risky. for a two main reasons:

1. you don't increment num_polynomial if index is bigger.
2. you don't know how bigger index is, so you might allocate a much bigger memory, and later, if you try to reach anything between the previous `num_polynomial` and the new size, you get to unknown area, and probably get segfault again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am still having the same issue :/ .  I can post my print function, but I am almost certain the issue is with the way that I am trying to insert an element.

Comment: Still no change.  Would probably be a good time for me to be able to effectively use GDB...

Comment: OK.  What I was doing wrong was I was only reallocating space for the polynomialArray without reallocating the index.  So I was trying to put a polynomial with 4 terms inside a polynomial with 2 terms.

Comment: @Cory - just out of curiosity - I don't understand what you did wrong, can you explain?

Comment: I thought I had it, but it is still messed up.  Basically if a the polynomial at the index I am inserting is larger than the index being inserted, then it sort of works.  If you insert a larger termed polynomial into an index that held a smaller termed polynomial, seg fault.  So confused.

Comment: How can they have different sizes? Term always holds 2 integers, and Polynomial always holds a pointer to Term. or do I get you all wrong?

Comment: The polynomialTerm is a dynamic array.

Comment: So I guess we are missing some part of your code here. Are you sure the problem is in insert()?

Comment: `free(&polynomialArray[index]);` tries to free the middle of a array; if `index==0` it will free the entire (presumably dynamically allocated) `polynomialArray`, otherwise it will (probably) crash.

Comment: You are right. it should be `free(polynomialArray[index]);` since you try to free the data in the address stored in `polynomialArray[index]`

Comment: @MByD, that can't be correct because on the previous line you used `polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm`, meaning `polynomialArray[index]` is a struct (or union), not a pointer.

Comment: I couldn't sleep because of that :) as David said, you can't free `polynomialArray[index]` , but you can't just do the assignment `polynomialArray[index] = *element; ` since they are structs. So I see two possible options: declare polynomialArray as `static Polynomial **polynomialArray;` (and change relevant methods) or use memcpy instead of `polynomialArray[index] = *element;`. now I can sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `subtract` is returning a pointer into your dynamically allocated array, but then `insert` realloc's that array, leaving the pointer returned by subtract (passed into insert as `element`) dangling.

So at the line you have marked `Problem here?`, element is pointing at the just implicitly freed (by realloc) array, which may well have been overwritten by the memory management system.  In any case, accessing memory after its freed gives undefined behavior.